# Why EntityFramework update context, but doesn't update database?

Tags: c#, sql, database, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have an `EntityFramework` test app. `Select` query is working good. I want to `Insert` a new row to my Database. I am doing this in following code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (Database1Entities context = new Database1Entities())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Current data in Table:");
            Console.WriteLine();

            var selectQuery = from person in context.Person
                              select person;

            foreach (var person in selectQuery)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}. {1} - {2}", person.id, person.Name, person.Age);
            }

            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("---------------------------------------");
            Console.WriteLine("Try to add the new object to a table:");
            Console.WriteLine();

            Person newItem = new Person();
            newItem.Name = "Tanya";
            newItem.Age = 20;

            context.Person.Add(newItem);
            context.SaveChanges();

            var selectQuery2 = from person in context.Person
                               select person;

            foreach (var person in selectQuery2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}. {1} - {2}", person.id, person.Name, person.Age);
            }
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

I have this output:

> Current data in Table:
>
> 1. Vlad - 20
> 2. Igor - 27
>
> ---
>
> Try to add the new object to a table:
>
> 1. Vlad - 20
> 2. Igor - 27
> 3. Tanya - 20

And this data in the database:

```
id   name    age
 1   Vlad     20
 2   Igor     27
```

The output shows that changes takes place, but the Database is not updated, there are no changes!

Comment: Your output seems to disagree with you.  Have you tried closing the context and opening a new one before doing your select query?  I think you'll find that Tanya is still there.

Comment: Tried, but no effect. Tanya is saved in contex, but not saved in database!

Comment: Has this ever worked for you before?  Is the database that you are checking the same one that your context is connected to?  Are you looking in the right table?  You're going to feel real silly when you find out what the actual problem is.

Comment: I am trying this first time. I created local DB and made EDM model of it. And i have only one table - **Person**. I really don't understand what is the problem

Comment: Remove the second SELECT statement and FOREACH from your program, and just run the program again to verify the record addition.

Comment: Removed. Tried 3 variants of updating. Nothing changed. Head broken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try doing like this

```
Context.Set<Person>().Add(newItem);
Context.SaveChanges();
```

Edit 1

If above solution didn't work try changing the entity state like this

```
Context.Entry<Person>(newItem).State = EntityState.Added;
Context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work for me =((

Comment: @user2932802 did you check as per Robert Harvey's sugession? Also see the edited answer

Comment: second variant i tried before question. this isn't working too =(

Answer (score 0):

ohhh, it's my fail. I was looking for changes in DB which is in project, not in debug folder. If i start program from debug folder it's works okay.